# Tips about optimizing this multi-layered (with many layers of subqueries) SQL query

Tags: sql, subquery, amazon-redshift, query-performance

I need your kind help with this SQL query. I have a query with 6 layers of subqueries that's currently structured like this. I am looking forward to advice how to:

1. Reduce the layers without repeating the same statement (for example, I could replace 'case when E>200' with '(Case when T2.BB >100 then B+C else B+D end) > 200' and write the statement in layer 1, hence eliminating layer2. I can't do this because in my raw queries I have a computed column that is based on another computed column in its sub-query, which is then calculated based on another computed column in the sub-sub-query... So repeating codes 5/6 time will confuse me and drive me crazy...
2. Avoid using select 2.*, select 1.* while still keeping all the columns (F,E,A,B,C,D,T2.BB) in the final output. I want to do this because in my raw query there is 5 select.* -- I feel like this causes the servers to do much redundant work and slows down query execution.

Thanks very much for your help!

```
Select 
    2.*,
    case when E > 200 then 'OK' else 'OH NO' end F
From
    (Select 
         1.*,
         Case when T2.BB >100 then B+C else B+D end E
     From
         (Select
              A, B, C, D, T2.BB
          From 
              T1
          Join 
              T2 on T1.A = T2.AA) 1
    ) 2
```

Comment: We'll need to know what database you're using

Comment: "I feel like this causes the servers to do much redundant work" You can be sure only if you do analyse the query plan since engien can optmize it under the hood

Comment: Hi @gjvdkamp. It's Amazon Redshift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try WITH statements, they look cleaner because they help to maintain the order in which you apply the logic, so it will look like this:

```
WITH
t1 as (
    select ...
    from src_table
)
,t2 as (
    select *, ...
    from t1
)
<<as much layers as needed>>
```

also if you need to reuse something in 2 different places you can reference the prior WITH statement from any following statement, i.e. encapsulate that logic in one place

Comment: Hi Alex. Thanks for your tips. I used your approach and improved SQL execution performance.